# JSF Primefaces 6.2 update - p:selectOneMenu display issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

we just upgraded to 6.2 primefaces in our JSF Application and found that p:selectOneMenu dropdown box was having an extra grey space next to the drop down arrow like below :

[image]

Kindly suggest if there is a workaround to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any custom css added?

Comment: Also what theme are you using?  It looks like "Aristo" from the screenshot.  Just an FYI Aristo has been deprecated for the new default theme Omega.

Comment: Using bootstrap theme :  

<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
 </context-param>

Is this not supported by primefaces 6.2?

Comment: No that theme should be OK but have you tried it in any other theme?  Just wondering if its related to Bootstrap theme or its an overall problem.

Answer (score 1):

On adding the below padding change in my custom css, the display issue was resolved:

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce using the PF Showcase. Here are the steps.

1. Navigate to: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml
2. In the upper right corner select Themes and choose Bootstrap.

[image]

Comment: yeah, in the primefaces showcase i dint get it too. Does primefaces showcase use 6.2 version ?

Comment: Yes it does use 6.2. So I think you might have a custom css style you introduced in your own CSS that is causing this.  Try either reproducing it outside your project or use Chrome and inspect the CSS if you see any styles from your own included CSS

Comment: Thanks Melloware :) I am new to JSF.. there was a padding added which caused this like you mentioned.

Comment: Ok great then add and answer with that solution in it and mark this question as answered!